# How would you approach this simple string parsing problem?

Tags: c#, string, parsing

```
"\n                                \n                                    Expected:\n                                    \n                                        \n                                            Q4\n                                        \n                                    \n                                    2011\n                                \n                            "
```

From that string, I need to get the following:

```
"Expected Q4 2011"
```

I've tried the following and no dice:

```
myString.Trim().Replace("\n", "");
```

I get the following (the massive whitespace is intentional and not a site formatter issue. That is in fact what is returned.)

```
"Expected:                                                                                                                        Q4                                                                                                                2011"
```

Comment: Your `Replace` did what it was supposed to do, which was remove the newlines.  If you want to remove the spaces as well, you need to include that in your replace, or perform another replace for the spaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace all white space blocks with a single space:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"\s+", " ").Trim();
```

Comment: I like this - even shorter than my way.

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to do this, but here's a short way:

```
string foo = "\n \n Expected:\n \n \n Q4\n \n \n 2011\n \n ";
string[] foos = foo.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n' },
                          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string bar = string.Join(" ", foos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var partsSplitByWhitespace = myString.Split(new[] {' ', '\n'}, 
                                                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var combinedStringAgain = string.Join(" ", partsSplitByWhitespace);
var result = combinedStringAgain.Trim();
```

Assuming you are sure the spaces are really space characters.

Answer (score 0):

If it is fair to say that you want all non-alphanumeric characters removed (whitespace, punctuation & symbol characters), you can use the following regular expression:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(@"[\W_]+", myString, " ");
```

`\W` is the inverse of `\w`, which matches all alphanumerics (0-9, a-z, A-Z) and the underscore.